# Next.js hosting on Vercel causes timeouts and hosting on Render fails on build

Tags: next.js, deployment, hosting, render, vercel

I am trying to host my Next.js application. I tried with Vercel of course, but when I try to run my login API route it times out after 10 seconds, even though when ran locally it runs instantly. I tried with Render.com, but when I try to deploy, the build fails saying that 'next' is not a valid command when trying to run 'next build'.
I am on the verge of giving up since I tried many ways to optimize the login route and I still cannot get it to not time out on Vercel and Render just doesn't want to deploy. Here is the api/login.ts file, I am open for any suggestions to optimizing it, or any suggestions on how to make Render recognize 'next' as a command.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import connectMongo from '../../database/connection';

import User from '@/models/User';
import { serialize } from 'cookie';

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await connectMongo();

const {username, password} = req.body;

const user = await User.findOne({username: username});

if (!user) {
  return res.status(400).send({message: 'No such user found!'});
}

if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
  return res.status(400).send({message: 'Invalid password!'});
}

const sessionToken = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SESSION_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize('sessionToken', sessionToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'strict', 
  maxAge: 60 * 60  * 24,
  path: '/'
}));
      
res.status(200).send({message: 'Successful login!'});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal server error!'});
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to host on netlify should be okay even if free tier